# ASP.Net Core 2.2 Scoped Service values update

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.2. I have a Scoped service injected in the HTTP request pipeline through Constructor injection. This service serves to carry the properties of the HTTP request context down the execution pipeline and it gets the values from the HTTP request query string or body. I would like to propagate the values of the scoped service properties downstream from the Controller method to the services. How do I achieve that?

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly AuthzContext _context;
    private readonly IHomeService _service;
    public HomeController(AuthzContext context, IHomeService service)
    {
        _context = context; // All properties are with default values at this time
        _service = service;
    }
    [HttpGet("{userId}/{sessionId]")]
    public async Task<Info> GetInfo(string userId, string sessionId)
    {
        _context.UserId = userId;
        _context.SessionId = sessionId;
        return await _service.GetInfo();
    }
}
public class HomeService : IHomeService
{
    private readonly AuthzContext _context;
    public HomeService(AuthzContext context) => _context = context; // All properties are with default values at this time
    public async Task<Info> GetInfo()
    {
        Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_context.UserId));
        Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_context.SessionId));
        // Do other complicated stuff or Call other services which require access to the same AuthzContext
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<AuthzContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IHomeService, HomeService>();
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking? Are you just asking how to pass them down a level to another service?

Comment: I have updated my question with code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you just pass the context through the parameters on the HomeService method? You don't need to inject it as you want to keep the context of the `AuthzContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand your question correctly but as far As I understand you want to access values from a scoped service that you set via whatever `AuthzContext` may be .

I believe you might be looking for the [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

So Ideally you'd want to write a scoped service (instance per request) that injects the `IHttpContextAccessor` (singleton) that sets and gets the values from the context and then you can inject that scoped service into your service layer at your leisure.